# Cannot build cube with apache kylin

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, sqoop, kylin

I have installed Apache Kylin in Hortonworks's HDP Sandbox image. Following this I have connected Apache Kylin to our Microsoft SQL Data Warehouse and when I try to build a cube the process is failing.

```
19/06/25 15:35:54 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7.3.0.1.0-187
19/06/25 15:35:54 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
19/06/25 15:35:54 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
19/06/25 15:35:54 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
19/06/25 15:35:54 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
19/06/25 15:35:55 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT `V_FACTTRANSACTION_CUBE`.`CUSTOMERFK` as `V_FACTTRANSACTION_CUBE_CUSTOMERFK`
...
19/06/25 15:35:55 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '`'.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '`'.
```

Seems like Sqoop is generating the query incorrectly by using "`" instead of normal quotes. Is there any way I can configure Sqoop to use the correct syntax ?

Comment: Maybe if you can help on this issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68918335/kylin-additional-data-sources-like-sql-server) i can help in this one after i connect the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sqoop 2 and make all SQL queries uppercase.it's a known issue in Kylin.