# Kylin Additional Data Sources like SQL Server

Tags: pip, database-connection, apache-superset, kylin

I have a Kubernetes cluster with Kylin for Back-End and Superset as Front-End.

Everything works great for the example "Default" database within the Kylin application.

Now I am trying to add SQL Server database where I have added the following code into `$KYLIN_HOME/conf/kylin.properties` file:

```
kylin.source.default=8 
kylin.source.jdbc.connection-url=jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:1433;database=sample
kylin.source.jdbc.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
kylin.source.jdbc.dialect=mssql 
kylin.source.jdbc.user=your_username 
kylin.source.jdbc.pass=your_password 
kylin.source.jdbc.sqoop-home=/usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client 
kylin.source.jdbc.filed-delimiter=|
```

As documentation describes I also added the `SQL-SERVER-JDBC-Database-Driver` jar file into `$KYLIN_HOME/ext/ directory`.

In addition, the documentation also mentions installing `SQOOP` and add the `SQL-SERVER-JDBC-Database-Driver` jar file also in the `$SQOOP_HOME/lib/` directory.

But inside the container I do not have pip to install it, so should I create a new image with `pip` and `SQOOP` installed? Is this the right way? And what `Kylin` needs?

**UPDATE**

After some investigation, managed to install also pip in case I needed it because originally I was thinking that I should install pysqoop which didn't work. Documentation is suggesting to install Apache SQOOP, and I am not sure what I should download and where to place the files.

Answer (score 0):

Kylin has a document on [Setup JDBC Data Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kylin).

The sqoop is [Apache Sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/), a bulk data transferring tool on Hadoop. Written in Java, kylin and sqoop has no need for python and pip.

Suggest investigate further in the Hadoop world. :-)